# How to enable AWS XRAY tracing for pymysql lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pymysql, aws-xray

I am having a lambda function created in python. It inserts the data in MySQL using pymysql library. How can I enable AWS xray tracing for database operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AWS X-Ray SDK for Python currently does not support tracing of mysql using pymysql. We do have a [pull request](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/pull/215) opened very recently which adds the support. We will review the PR and get it merged as soon as possible. Please stay tuned to our SDK for updates.

Thanks.